# Zoom waiting room -- How to ensure only host can see new participants?

Tags: zoom-meeting

I was recently participant, **not** host, in a Zoom meeting room.

Then apparently some other user tried to enter the meeting. Even though I was not host I was told the name (!) of the other user and was offered to let them in

"User XY entered the waiting room. Admit?"

Does anyone know how to disable this feature? For privacy reasons (e.g., when running interviews), I prefer that other participants do not see who is trying to enter the room.

Comment: The Host can see all participants.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I'm aware, a standrd participant shouldn't be notified when someone is in the waiting room. This leaves a few possibilities:

1. It was a glitch, in which case you should contact Zoom support
2. You were somehow a cohost without realizing it (seems unlikely, but still possible)
3. **Most Likely:** The host has their account configured so that you bypassed the waiting room and as a result had the ability to admit people from the waiting room

Option 3 requires two settings to be configured:

1. [Who goes into the waiting room](https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/115000332726-Waiting-Room#:%7E:text=Who%20should%20go%20into%20the%20waiting%20room%3F) set to a value that allowed you to bypass it
2. [Who can admit participants from the waiting room](https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/115000332726-Waiting-Room#:%7E:text=Who%20can%20admit%20participants%20from%20the%20waiting%20room%3F) set to include people that bypassed the waiting room

Option 3 also requires that "host and co-hosts are not present"

Overall, it's unlikely other participants will get notified unlesss very specific circumstances are met. I tested it out using my Zoom account and only the host was notified when someone joined the waiting room.

Comment: It wasn’t a glitch, it’s a feature of Zoom, and how the room was configured.